# Excel removes Data Validation at launch

Tags: excel, vba

[image: Capture]

I created Data Validation using VBA and the code worked perfectly when the excel file was open. However, when I closed and reopened it, Excel threw an error as the attached capture.

```
Sub SetupDataValidation()

    Dim wsContactSheet As Worksheet
    Dim ContactTable As ListObject
    Dim lastrowContactTable As Long
    Dim validationRange As Range
    Dim validationFormula As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim supportToAdd As Worksheet
    Dim inputTrainer As String

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    ' Set worksheet and table references
    Set wsContactSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ContactSheet")
    Set ContactTable = wsContactSheet.ListObjects("AM")
    Set supportToAdd = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SupportToAdd")
    
    ' Get trainer name to compare with the names in column F of table AM
    inputTrainer = supportToAdd.Range("A1").Value

  
    ' Construct the validation formula
    For i = 2 To ContactTable.ListRows.Count
        If Not IsEmpty(wsContactSheet.Cells(i, 6).Value) And wsContactSheet.Cells(i, 6).Value = inputTrainer Then
            validationFormula = validationFormula & "," & wsContactSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value
        End If
    Next i


    ' Apply data validation to the specified range
    On Error Resume Next ' Turn on error handling
    Set validationRange = supportToAdd.Range("D3")
    If Not validationRange Is Nothing Then
        With validationRange.Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=validationFormula
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "Range D3 not found in the worksheet", vbExclamation
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0 ' Reset error handling

    
    ' Assign D3 value with the first value in the data validation list
   If Not IsEmpty(supportToAdd.Range("D3").Validation.Formula1) Then
        Dim firstValue As String
        firstValue = Split(Mid(validationFormula, 2), ",")(0)
        supportToAdd.Range("D3").Value = firstValue
    End If
    Exit Sub
    
ErrorHandler:
        MsgBox "An error occurred: " & Err.Description, vbCritical
        
    End Sub
```

Please help read the code below and give me a few suggestions.

Comment: What’s the final length of validationFormula ?   Excel can’t handle more than 256 characters, but the problem only shows up when you reopen the saved file.

Comment: ….if your lists are longer than that you’d need to put them in a range instead

Comment: @TimWilliams Hi Tim, thank you for your response. I used range as the following code but excel said that .add method in the validation construction does not work.

Comment: `   For i = 2 To ContactTable.ListRows.Count
            If validationRange Is Nothing Then
                Set validationRange = wsContactSheet.Cells(i, 1)
            Else
                Set validationRange = Union(validationRange, wsContactSheet.Cells(i, 1))
...
        With validationCell.Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=" & validationRange.Address
...

Comment: The range needs to be a contiguous range. You can’t use a multi-area range, so you’ll need to write the list to a worksheet somewhere (you could use a hidden sheet if you prefer) and reference that range from the validation.

Comment: Hi Tim, I wrote the list to a hidden sheet and the code worked now! Really appreciate your help!